# Testing 433MHz Transmitter

Tags: atmega2560

Folks,

There is a document named "[Complete Guide for RF 433MHz Transmitter.pdf](http://www.energiazero.org/arduino_sensori/Complete%20Guide%20for%20RF%20433MHz%20Transmitter.pdf)" available in the GitHub.

There is a a connection diagram showing the Data pin of the Transmitter connected to the pin 12 of the Arduino Uno.

The Transmitter sketch given in it is as follows:

```cpp
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> // Not actually used but needed to compile

RH_ASK driver;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
 if (!driver.init())
 Serial.println("init failed");
}

void loop()
{
 const char *msg = "Hello World!";
 driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
 driver.waitPacketSent();
 delay(1000);
}
```

There is no mention of Pin 12 as part of the sketch. I am not sure how the Arduino knows the Transmitter Data input is connected to the Pin 12? Can someone please help?

Ranjith

Answer (score 2):

In [RH_ASK.h](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/RH__ASK_8h_source.html#l00278) is:

```cpp
RH_ASK(uint16_t speed = 2000, uint8_t rxPin = 11, uint8_t txPin = 12, uint8_t pttPin = 10, bool pttInverted = false);
```

So the argument has a [default value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) specified here.  If you don't specify it, it assumes that default.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.